# Sample S2 images, getting the closes pixel for nodata

Tags: google-earth-engine

I got something like this:

```
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');
function quick_cld(img){
  return cld.sclMask(['cloud_low', 'cloud_medium', 'cloud_high', 'shadow'])(img)
}

var img = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '34UDE')
  .filterDate('2021-03-01', '2021-09-30')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)).map(quick_cld)
  .select('B.*').toBands();

roi = img.geometry()

var sample = img.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 1500,
  region: roi,
  scale: 10,
  geometries: true,
  dropNulls: false
});
```

But the problem is, that the sample properies counts are not even, because there are 3 orbits going through that tile, only one of them fully, others have like half of nodata pixels (and that property gets dropped in sample).

I don't want to drop the ones that have nodata on some image, but instead get the closest one that has a data. Any idea how to effectively do that?

Comment: When you say `closest one`, do you mean spatially or temporal? I'm also not sure I follow what you're trying to with `stratifiedSample()`. It sample `numPoints` for every unique value in `img`. But `img` isn't a categorical image.

Comment: For filling gaps spatially, you can look at `focalMedian()`. Maybe something like this could be a starting point: https://code.earthengine.google.com/902fb77cee68cedf94304283c5326d99

Comment: @DanielWiell I mean temporal. It can't be a median, as it will do it spatially. But thank You for Your comment. In my case spatial fill won't occur, as some images have like 80% of nodata because of orbit (for example orbit 122)... to check what I mean display the first image of the collection... `var img = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '34UDE').filterDate('2021-03-01', '2021-09-30').filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)).first()`

Comment: What's the final output you're looking for, at the end of the day? Time-series for random points in your AOI?

Comment: @DanielWiell values of all points of all images in selected tile collection with filled nodata values from the closest image in time that has a data in there